# Convert database time to IST datetime

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, time, timezone

I have a time value stored in my database in `HH:mm:ss` format (using MySQL's `time` type). This time is to be considered as a value of IST timezone. The server on which my Java code runs follows the UTC timezone.

How can I get a formatted datetime in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in IST (or in UTC millis)? Following is what I've tried till now:

```
// ... Code truncated for brevity
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalTime time = resultSet.getTime("send_time").toLocalTime();
LocalDateTime datetime = time.atDate(LocalDate.now());
System.out.println(datetime.format(formatter));
```

The above correctly prints the datetime on my local machine, which is on IST, but I'm concerned about how it will behave on the remote server.

Comment: If you can, prefer `LocalTime time = resultSet.getObject("send_time", LocalTime.class);`. It requires a newer JDBC driver (JDBC version 4.2), but I believe MySQL had such a Connector/J out pretty early, so you may be in luck with the one you have.

Comment: @OleV.V. -- Thanks for your comment. I am using MyBatis to get this, and I've written a custom type handler for it. For this question only, I've demonstrated that I'm getting it using ResultSet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is fine and should work regardless of your computer's time zone since there is no time zone information in either `LocalTime` or `LocalDateTime`. One possible issue is with `LocalDate.now()` which returns today's date in the computer's local time zone, not in IST. You may want to replace it with `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta"))`.

Or as commented by @OleV.V. you could use the new driver facilities to derive a `LocalTime` directly:

```
LocalTime time = resultSet.getObject("send_time", LocalTime.class);
```

Note possible caveats with your approach:

- if the time zone you use introduces DST, you may end up with two identical times in  your DB that were actually different instants - using UTC to store times is probably more robust
- `time` in mysql can store values smaller than `00:00` and larger than `23:59:59.999999`, in which case you may experience unexpected behaviours on the Java side.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The major part was to get `LocalDate` in Indian timezone, which is solved now. In the notes, first is not applicable to me because the time will always be in IST. For the second one, I would like to know more. Could you please suggest any online material to go through?

Comment: I looked at [The TIME Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) in the MySQL Reference Manual. Compare to [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) in the Java API documentation. If you are making sure to save times in the interval 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.999999, I can’t believe you will see any issue, though.

Comment: @31piy Also note that you can test your code by changing your JVM timezone with `TimeZone.setDefault(zone);`. Ideally, you should make the change before loading the mysql driver and opening the connection to make sure it's taken into account.